# jQuery, increment id when dynamically appending elements cannot get values

Tags: jquery

```js
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").append('<div class="row ' + counter + '"><div class="form-horizontal ' + counter + '"><div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="txtfname' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="txtlname' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="textaddress' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address"></div></div></div></div>');
    counter++;
    return false;

})

$(document).on('click', '#add', function ()
{
    if(counter > 0){
        var inputName = $('#txtfname' + counter).val();

        debugger;
      //  var ele = $(jQuery.trim('#txtfname'+counter.toString())).val();
      //  var name = inputName.valueOf()

        if (jQuery.trim(inputName).length > 0)
        {
            $(ele).prop('disabled', true);
          
            alert("First name filled");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Nothing Filled");
        }
}
  
    $("#container").append('<div class="row ' + counter + '"><div class="form-horizontal ' + counter + '"><div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="txtfname' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="txtlname' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="textaddress' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address"></div></div></div></div>');
    counter++;
    return false;

});

$("#remove").click(function () {
    if (counter == 1) {
        alert("No more author to remove");
        return false;
    }

    counter--;

  //  $(".row" + counter).remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
        ></script>
<div id="container">
</div>

<div>      
   <input type="button" id="add" value="Add input Row"/>
   <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove input Row"/>
  
</div>
```

I cannot get the value from `div` using `val()` function
for an example

```
var inputName = $('#txtfname' + counter).val(); // inputName= '#txtfname1'
```

I wanted to get entered value in `txtfname` field but I could not get that 
please help

[This is my code in html view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuYuU.jpg)

```
var counter = 1;

$(document).on('click', '#add', function ()
{
    if(counter > 0){
        var inputName = $('#txtfname' + counter).val();

        if (jQuery.trim(inputName).length > 0) {
            $(inputName).prop('disabled', true);
            alert("First name filled");
        } else {
           alert("something else");
    }
}

// debugger; 
$("#container").append('<div class="row ' + counter + '"><div class="form-horizontal ' + counter + '"><div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="txtfname' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="txtlname' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><input id="textaddress' + counter + '" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address"></div></div></div></div>');
    counter++;
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using your browsers Dom Explorer (Developper Tools) to inspect if your HTML is correctly generated and your input has really the id set that you intend to?

Comment: does your click event fire up? and also can you get the element by classic getElementById?

Comment: yeah the  alert("First name filled"); also poped up but the thing is i can't get the value that i inserted on textbox

Comment: document.getElementById('#txtfname' + counter);
returns
null

Comment: it is possible you will get "NaN" with counter being numeric. Try var elm='#txtfname'+counter.toString(); document.getElementById(elm);

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually get the content of a div with `val()`, use `text()` instead